# Select multiple columns with min value

Tags: mysql, sql

Example schema:

```
id val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 mid
1   5     6    7    1    4   1
4   7     8    5    9    5   1
5   4     1    4    2    7   2
7   3     2    8    7    2   1
```

Here is what im trying, but this query returns only 1 row with all values:

```
SELECT id, MIN(val1), MIN(val2), MIN(val3), MIN(val4), MIN(val5) FROM table WHERE mid=1
```

I want results to be (for each val column select id,min as min(valx) where mid=1):

```
id min
7   3
7   2
4   5
1   1
7   2
```

One note: amount of columns can be up to 50 (valx where x is number from 1 to 50).

Comment: 50 columns sounds like bad table design to me.  The aggregate functions, such as `MIN`, were meant to operate over records, not columns.

Comment: You need to add GROUP BY id at the end of your statement.

Comment: It is not clear. How do you get the desired result?

Comment: What are you using mid for? I think I understand what you're trying to do, but in your desired output, you produced (5, 1) and (5, 4) but mid = 2 not 1?

Comment: @FrumRoll Yes you're right, i fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: So how do you get 3 results for id 7?

Comment: @P.Salmon Because for id 7, val1, val2, val5 are the smallest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, val1 from table where val1=(select min(val1) from table where mid=1) and mid=1
union all
select id, val2 from table where val2=(select min(val2) from table where mid=1) and mid=1
union all
select id, val3 from table where val3=(select min(val3) from table where mid=1) and mid=1
union all
select id, val4 from table where val4=(select min(val4) from table where mid=1) and mid=1
union all
select id, val5 from table where val5=(select min(val5) from table where mid=1) and mid=1
```

Comment: Your query gives me only 1 row with smallest val1.

Comment: I tried in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/451cb/5 and it gives me exactly your desired output

Comment: Maybe thats problem with my database or problem with float system that im using for my val columns. Edit: probably problem with my db, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd7ac/2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, minimum
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(Val1) as minimum FROM TableName WHERE Mid = 1) v1
    INNER JOIN TableName t1
    ON v1.minimum = t1.Val1
    AND t1.Mid = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT id, minimum
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(Val2) as minimum FROM TableName WHERE Mid = 1) v2
    INNER JOIN TableName t2
    ON v2.minimum = t2.Val2
    AND t2.Mid = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT id, minimum
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(Val3) as minimum FROM TableName WHERE Mid = 1) v3
    INNER JOIN TableName t3
    ON v3.minimum = t3.Val3
    AND t3.Mid = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT id, minimum
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(Val4) as minimum FROM TableName WHERE Mid = 1) v4
    INNER JOIN TableName t4
    ON v4.minimum = t4.Val4
    AND t4.Mid = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT id, minimum
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(Val5) as minimum FROM TableName WHERE Mid = 1) v5
    INNER JOIN TableName t5
    ON v5.minimum = t5.Val5
    AND t5.Mid = 1
```

This is just a nasty nasty query and situation but I figured out what you want.  If you improve your narrative you might be get some better answers than this one.

Here is what I took your desired results and narrative to mean.

Find the Minimum value of each column where Mid = 1, then Find the ID(s) that relate to that minimum value.  The results of above are:

```
id  minimum
7   3
7   2
4   5
1   1
7   2
```

Note the 4 5 pair you actually have 5 4 but 5 would be the minimum value in Val3 because 4 represented is where mid = 2.  So the ID for value 5 is 4....

Comment: Your query works as i wanted! But is too big a little. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LEAST()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/least.php) function...

```
select id, least(val1, val2, <etc>)
from myTable
where mid=1
```

Comment: This is not works like i want. It gives me rows with min value only from val1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly  I hope It will help you

```
 SELECT id, MIN(minimum) as minimum FROM (
 SELECT id, val1 As minimum FROM table where  mid=1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, val2 As minimum FROM table where  mid=1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, val3 As minimum FROM table where  mid=1
 union All
 SELECT id, val4 As minimum FROM table  where  mid=1
 union ALL
 SELECT id, val5 As minimum FROM table where  mid=1
 ) As minvalue
 GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This is not works like i want. It gives me rows with min value only from val1.

Comment: Im looking for query that gives 5 rows with smallest value for val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 not smallest from list(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous answer, didn't see your result.
I hope this will give you the result.

```
;with cte as(
    Select a.ID
        , t.Val
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.id order by t.ColNo) as ColNo
    From @TABLE as a
    Outer apply (Values (1,Val1), (2,Val2),(3,Val3),(4,Val4), (5,Val5) ) t(ColNo,Val)
    Where a.MID=1
)
, cte2 as( 
    Select ColNo, MIN(val) as MinVal 
    From cte
    Group by ColNo
) 
    Select a.ID, a.Val from cte as a
    Inner join cte2 as b on a.ColNo=b.ColNo and a.Val=b.MinVal
    Order by a.ColNo
```

Comment: Your group by is excluding (7, 3) and the duplicate (7, 2).

Comment: I don't think MySQL has `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: @Barmar is right. Unrecognized keyword. (near "Outer" at position 65)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id, MIN(val1), MIN(val2), MIN(val3), MIN(val4), MIN(val5) 
FROM table 
WHERE mid=1 
GROUP by id
```

Comment: Your query gives me rows with all columns.

Comment: Thanks ruffp. this code is just a simple select/group by. after posting, discovered that this is not what the asker wants. I posted another one, which answer the problem but for SQL-Server.